# How to save files OUTSIDE the Eclipse IDE workspace?

Tags: eclipse, ide, savefiledialog

I have opened a file in the text editor inside Eclipse IDE.
When I click <kbd>File</kbd>=><kbd>Save As</kbd> a dialog will pop up listing all projects **inside** the workspace.

So it is not possible to save this file **outside** the Eclipse workspace.

Is it possible to open the OS `File Save` dialog so that I can save my file outside the Eclipse workspace? (I'm looking for something similar to the `Save As` feature in other text editors like notepad++, gedit, geany etc. etc.)

Comment: Is there a 'save as'?

Comment: Corrected my question.

Answer (score 2):

The base Eclipse text editor will open the OS File Save dialog (actually `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileSaveDialog`) if the file being edited is not in the workspace. If the file is in the workspace the workspace Save As dialog used (`org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.SaveAsDialog`).

I can't see any way to get it to show the OS file save dialog for a workspace file.

Answer (score 0):

Select the file you want to save in the package explorer, right click and select Export...

Select File System and click Next, then you can select any file system location

[image: select file system]

Comment: But this is not working as in other simple editors. Ex modify a file and try to export as shown above.Then eclipse ask whether to save the file content.If you say No then the modified content will not be saved and you cannot rename this file. Usually in other editors when you modify a file then click on Save as button then you can able to rename the file and after renaming the old file will be closed and the new file is automatically opened with the content saved by default.

Comment: So you're trying to save a file outside the workspace, without first saving it in the workspace?

Comment: Yes.The same way how **Save As** file works in other editors like notepad, notepad++, geany etc etc

Comment: I just wanted to save a copy of a class to my shared folder, so this worked great, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is probably to save the file in your workspace (using **Save as** so you don't overwrite the original file) and then copy that file somewhere else. You can simply move the file (rather than copying), but this will close the editor.

Comment: This is not direct answer. Probably it can be added as comment.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Then I suppose the "answer" you're looking for is *No*.

Comment: No. I am expecting any work arounds/tweaks to open OS **File Save As** dialog on workspace resource itself. OR any utility plug-ins to do this. Note that as @greg-449 said that we can open OS **File Save As** dialog on non-workspace resource BUT not on workspace resource.

Comment: "You can do it another way" answers are appropriate.